# Where should I ask BSS/OSS questions (most programming) regarding telecommunication?

Tags: discussion

I am a developer building BSS/OSS software. I have some questions regarding how to fit my software into industry standard.

I am wondering where should I ask those questions?

The questions will be like :

1. What is the "industry standard" way of writing telecom OSS software? I heard of TMF eTom model. But is it the standard or there's something else?
2. Besides, I need to write the software in a way that it should:

   a. follow standard business procedure

   b. easy integration with other vendor's BSS/OSS software in technical way.

Comment: Would you mind sharing more details about the questions you have?  We can try to help refine them if they are on-topic here.

Comment: Sorry for reply late. Can you review my questions?